# Why is the method strikethrough?

Tags: xcode8

I have defined a class like this:

```
internal class C {
    internal func method() -> Void {
        print("method called")
    }
}
```

If I declare a closure from that method, the method is shown strikethrough

```
let closure = C.init().meth
let closure2 = C.meth
```

The same happens if I use it in the autocasting paranthesis `\(...)`

```
print("\(C.init().meth)")
```

#### Xcode examples:

[image: example1]
[image: example2]
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The strike-through is happening because your function `method()` returns nothing. The contexts that you're trying to complete in (assignment and interpolation) both expect values, so a method that returns `Void` is not recommended there.

You will see the same strikethrough if you try to assign the result of **system** functions that returns nothing e.g. if you do:

```
var arr = [1,2,3]
arr.append(4) // no strikethrough
let result = arr.append(5) // you will see strikethough on 'append'
```

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. Xcode does not see in the closure case that it is thr method itself that I want to set as a value